# Warning #3180: unrecognized OpenMP #pragma. Have checked other answers but none correspond to my issue

Tags: c, parallel-processing, openmp, compiler-warnings

I am getting this warning for my code. It still lets me run the program but it acts as if its single threaded in terms of performance so I believe it is ignoring my pragma. I am compiling with these flags:
`icc main.o print_output.o -O3 -fopenmp -o -programname`

this is my pragma statement in my code:

```
#pragma omp parallel for private(waat)
for ( ...){
...
}
```

I have made sure to #include <omp.h> as well. I have also declared the number of threads by the following commands:

```
omp_set_dynamic(0);
omp_set_num_threads(4);
```

not sure why I am getting this error. Any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Would you mind to update your post so as to contain a reproducible icc-compilation problem? You may enjoy the help of a widely configurable webIDE from Godbolt on https://godbolt.org/z/ez35cz to elaborate your MCVE / MWE to get referred / reposted here. That's fair, isn't it?

Comment: There are no source files in your compilation command, just object ones. Please show us the real compilation command. ICC produces **warning #3180** when you are not passing `-qopenmp` or `-fopenmp` while compiling code that has OpenMP pragmas in it.

Comment: Hello, that is my compilation command from my Makefile. It compiles just fine using that command except it gives me the 3180 error on my pragma. I am including the fopenmp and have tried qopenmp instead but got same issue

Comment: Notice the `.o` in `main.o print_output.o`. Those are **object** files, not source code. There is a different line somewhere which specifies how C files are compiled. You may need to alter `CFLAGS` and include `-qopenmp` there.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my question! It was an error in my makefile. I was including -fopenmp in the object line for the application but not compiling my actual main.c with the -fopenmp. Thank you to everyone who responded!